# Are there abandoned ships in X3: Albion Prelude?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

Has anyone found any abandoned ships in Albion Prelude.
Perhaps they are the same as Terran Confict?

I would like to know if there are abandoned ships that I can claim to kickstart a little money.

Thanks

Comment: If you go to the Stock Exchange in Nyanas Hideout you will make millions in minutes.
Buy shares at index 100 from buyer perspective and sell when they get low.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I gather (i.e. digging around on egosoft forums and exploring the game), abandoned ships in the galaxy are now randomized, so they're no longer in a predetermined position.

If you are having trouble with money, make your way to the Omicron Lyrae area (I hung around in Circle of Labor a lot, which is just north of OL) and start looting the various missiles that gets dropped during the battles between Terrans and Argons.  You can easily make 1 mill in half an hour.

Just make sure you don't wander into a stray PSP or you'll be instantly vaporized.

Comment: Also, If you play Terran Commandet, finding Aldrin and the Aldrin shipyard, then swapping your Katana for the Springblossom lets you complete the harder freight- and passenger (if you buy life support) missions. That'll give you millions in a matter of hours.

Comment: By far, the easiest and fastest way to make money in AP so far is to do stocks.  Just an hour of buying and selling naturals got me the 25 million to complete the poisoned paranid start.  Now I'm rocking along in my overtuned hyperion barely 8 game hours in.  The only hard part was actually getting to a stock exchange in the slow ass freighter you start out with.

Answer (score 1):

I have found 1 corvette in unknown sector, next to Xenon sector 534.

Stats:

- 39% damaged
- no shield
- 10 kyon beta
- 2 thorn missiles

Coordinates: 1.48 km X / -24.1 km Y / -855 Z
I found it while mining for nividium.
It was 25 km below the nividium 5 rock.

Comment: I also located the above ship in the above location.

Comment: In my game, the corvette was at the second to last Unknown Sector when searching for it by name, at 72k,~0,~0. This is almost certainly random for every new game one starts.